# zend validate user for a specific controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework

HI i would like to know how to validate a users for a specific controller, so that we can check that a specific users is authenticate before accessing resources of a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets says for a specific controller in controller folder we have CashoutController. Before a user accessing this controller we will authenticate the users as below with make use of custom library.

```
<?php
 class CashoutController extends Zc_Controller_Action_User
 {
  public function init()
  {
    /* Initialize action controller here */
    parent::init();
  }
    // rest code goes here
 }
```

now we defined new library name Zc

```
   <?php
   class Zc_Controller_Action_User extends Zc_Controller_Action
{ 
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    $this->validateAccess();
}

private function validateAccess()
{
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

    if (is_null($auth->getIdentity())) {
        $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index');
    }
}
    }
```

where we define controller action library as

```
<?php

class Birdtoldme_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

 }
```

hope this is has been an informative for you.

Answer (score 1):

you should take a look at Zend_Auth and Zend_Acl Component.

```
Zend_Auth is responsible for assigning and managing authentication of the user.

Zend_Acl is responsible for managing different permissions and roles for different resources.
```

here is the tutorial explaining how you can implement Zend_Auth.

http://akrabat.com/zend-auth-tutorial/

and the below tutorial explains about Zend_Auth/Zend_Acl

http://devzone.zend.com/844/zend_acl-zend_auth-example-scenario/